# Is this binary search in TypeScript correct?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, typescript

I need your help to see if the following binary search code is correct. I did my best to cover the corner cases.  I wonder if I missed anything.

The code as it is with tests (you can play with it online [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/)):

```
function binarySearch<a, r>(
    hay: a[],
    needle: a,
    compare:(one: a, another: a, oneGreaterThanAnother: () => r, oneLessThanAnother: () => r, oneEqualToAnother: () => r) => r,
    haveStaightHit: (hay: a[], index: number) => r,
    haveExpectedToBeAt: (hay: a[], index: number) => r
) {
    if (hay.length > 0) {
        return binarySearchUnsafe(hay, needle, 0, hay.length - 1, compare, haveStaightHit, haveExpectedToBeAt);
    } else {
        return haveExpectedToBeAt(hay, 0);
    }
}
function binarySearchUnsafe<a, r>(
    hay: a[],
    needle: a,
    from: number,
    to: number,
    compare:(one: a, another: a, oneGreaterThanAnother: () => r, oneLessThanAnother: () => r, oneEqualToAnother: () => r) => r,
    haveStaightHit: (hay: a[], index: number) => r,
    haveExpectedToBeAt: (hay: a[], index: number) => r
): r {
    if (from < to) {
        var at = from + (~~((to - from) / 2));
        return compare(
            needle,
            hay[at],
            function needleIsOnTheRight() {
                return binarySearchUnsafe(hay, needle, at + 1, to, compare, haveStaightHit, haveExpectedToBeAt);
            },
            function needleIsOnTheLeft() {
                return binarySearchUnsafe(hay, needle, from, at, compare, haveStaightHit, haveExpectedToBeAt);
            },
            function needleIsFound() {
                return haveStaightHit(hay, at);
            }
        );      
    } else if (from > to) {
        throw new Error('From index ' + from + ' is bigger than the to index ' + to + '.');
    } else {
        var at = from /* === to */;
        return compare(
            needle,
            hay[at],
            function needleIsOnTheRight() {
                return haveExpectedToBeAt(hay, at + 1);
            },
            function needleIsOnTheLeft() {
                return haveExpectedToBeAt(hay, at);             
            },
            function needleIsFound() {
                return haveStaightHit(hay, at)
            }
        );
    }
}

function areEqual(actual: any, expected: any) {
    if (actual !== expected) throw new Error('Expected: ' + expected + ', Actual: ' + actual);
}

function compareStrings<r>(one: string, another: string, oneGreaterThanAnother: () => r, oneLessThanAnother: () => r, oneEqualToAnother: () => r) : r {
    if (one > another) {
        return oneGreaterThanAnother();
    } else if (one < another) {
        return oneLessThanAnother();
    } else {
        return oneEqualToAnother();
    }
}

function failOver(message: string) : any {
    return function() {
        throw new Error(message);
    }
}

try {
    binarySearch([], 'x', compareStrings, failOver('Direct hit is not expected.'), (hay, index) => areEqual(index, 0));
    binarySearch(['b', 'd', 'f'], 'b', compareStrings, (hay, index) => areEqual(index, 0), failOver('Direct hit is expected.'));
    binarySearch(['b', 'd', 'f'], 'd', compareStrings, (hay, index) => areEqual(index, 1), failOver('Direct hit is expected.'));
    binarySearch(['b', 'd', 'f'], 'f', compareStrings, (hay, index) => areEqual(index, 2), failOver('Direct hit is expected.'));
    binarySearch(['b', 'd', 'f'], 'g', compareStrings, failOver('Direct hit is not expected.'), (hay, index) => areEqual(index, 3));
    binarySearch(['b', 'd', 'f'], 'a', compareStrings, failOver('Direct hit is not expected.'), (hay, index) => areEqual(index, 0));
    binarySearch(['b', 'd', 'f'], 'c', compareStrings, failOver('Direct hit is not expected.'), (hay, index) => areEqual(index, 1));
    alert('You are all good!');
} catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That looks jolly complicated.  If you haven't read it, look for Jon Bentley's *Programming Pearls* article on binary search.  Here's my version:

```
var bSearch = <T>(xs: T[], x: T, cmp: (p: T, q: T) => number): number => {
    var bot = 0;
    var top = xs.length;
    while (bot < top) { // If x is in xs, it's somewhere in xs[bot..top).
        var mid = Math.floor((bot + top) / 2);
        var c = cmp(xs[mid], x);
        if (c === 0) return mid;
        if (c < 0) bot = mid + 1;
        if (0 < c) top = mid; 
    }
    return -1;
}

var cmp = (p: number, q: number) => p - q;

console.log(bSearch([], 3, cmp) === -1);
console.log(bSearch([3], 3, cmp) === 0);
console.log(bSearch([1, 3], 3, cmp) === 1);
console.log(bSearch([3, 4], 3, cmp) === 0);
console.log(bSearch([3, 3], 3, cmp) !== -1);
console.log(bSearch([1, 2, 3], 3, cmp) === 2);
console.log(bSearch([1, 3, 4], 3, cmp) === 1);
console.log(bSearch([3, 4, 5], 3, cmp) === 0);
console.log(bSearch([4, 5, 6], 3, cmp) === -1);
```

Comment: Its not complicated, its just in a functional style. If the elemen isn't found my search results to the best expected position, yours always gets -1.

Comment: @bonomo, I'm a well seasoned functional programmer and I'm afraid I don't recognise the functional style in your approach.  It would be trivial to rewrite my implementation as a recursive function, if that's what you'd prefer to see.  Similarly, one could always return `mid` rather than -1 on failure to indicate a lower bound on where `x` "should" be.

Comment: http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/YAHT/Type_basics#Continuation_Passing_Style

Comment: If you always return mid you would have no way to tell apart a straight hit from a miss.

Comment: @bonomo, sure you do -- you just look up the item at the returned index.  Was it the one you were looking for?  Yes: hooray!  No: that's where it would go.

Comment: You would have to document such behavior somewhere, in my approach there is no need for this since it's explicit from usage. Again this is a benefit of using CPS: "Expressing code in this form makes a number of things explicit which are implicit in direct style." From here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style

Comment: By the way, I understand CPS, I just don't see its benefit here over a more conventional approach.  It would be dead easy to change to CPS if that's your preferred option -- I thought your question primarily concerned implementing binary search.

Comment: I asked to help me to veryfy if my code is correct, there was a bug in it when it alredy got 3 upvotes, you can check tgd history of edits. I hope there are no bugs anymore. There was no other concerns.

Comment: @bonomo, okey dokey.